# semantic xhtml markup for date on news detail page?

Tags: xhtml, semantics

is there a more semantic way than this markup FOR THE DATE on news detail pages?

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum <span>12.12.2010</span></h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 has a `<time>` tag.  If not using HTML 5, I would do this: `<span class='time'>` to indicate it is similar to HTML 5 time.  This would make it easy to style and find with Javascript automation.